# Creating a aws cli container to upload django postgres database backups to s3

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, docker

Ok, this will be a bit embarrassing, but I am trying to build a docker service with an aws cli that shares a volume with my backend for storage of backups.

I saw this approach in the package [django-cookiecutter](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django)

So far, I couldn't get anything to work and I really struggle with finding the right approach. I defined the access-key etc in my **docker-compose**:

```
services:
  aws_cli:
    build:
      context: ./kitschoen_aws_docker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxxxxxxxxxx
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxx
      - SQL_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
    volumes:
      - postgres_backup:/backup
volumes:
  postgres_backup:
```

And set up a **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM garland/aws-cli-docker:1.15.47

# ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "aws configure --region=eu-central-1 --output=text" ]
```

The commented out part does not work because the container does not seem to have a bash console. I am quite lost, at would be very grateful for any hint in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Don't be embarrassed, this sort of thing can seem simple but turn out to be frustratingly complicated. My first suggestion is to try changing your entrypoint to `/bin/sh` to see if that is available. It looks like the image you are using is based on [Alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/), so `/bin/sh` should be available, which should get you past this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by marked it is an alpine based image so try with `sh`, but real problem will start it this line

```
 ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "aws configure --region=eu-central-1 --output=text" ]
```

it will configure the `aws keys` but as soon as keys configured, the container will die.

So I will just to bind the host `credentials`, you will get two thing

- Already configured keys
- Existing configured profiles

docker-compose

```
version: '3'

services:
  aws_cli:
    image: garland/aws-cli-docker:1.15.47
    volumes:
      - /home/user/.aws/:/root/.aws
```

So now run that command or any other process that you want.

```
docker-compose run aws_cli aws s3api list-buckets --query "Buckets[].Name" --profile test
```

or any python script,

```
docker-compose run aws_cli python my.py
```